# Using the == operator to compare a char to 0x80 always results in false?

Tags: c++, types, binary, char, byte

```
char byte = 0x80
if(byte == 0x80)
{
    cout << "This message never gets printed!";
}
```

The hexadecimal value `0x80` is equivalent in binary to `1000 0000`, which clearly fits in a byte.

However, the compiler warns me about the line with the conditional:

```
warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type
```

Why is the result of the conditional false in this case?

Is `0x80` getting expanded in the conditional to something like `0x80000000`?

Is it possible to use the `==` operator to check if a `char` equals `0x80`?

Comment: `char` can be signed or unsigned.

Comment: Yes. But even if `0x80` resolves to a negative number, are we not just comparing whether the contents of the `char` are equal to the literal? If not, please explain! :)

Comment: @CoryKlein: `0x80` is an `int`.

Comment: This got me before. Very annoying.

Comment: What's even more annoying is that this comparison will actually return true on some architectures and false on others.  So code that was working will suddenly break when compiled for a different platform.  And in my case, the compiler issued no warning like you got.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `char` is, in the C and C++ standards, defined that it can be either a signed or an unsigned value, and that a `char` must have at least 8 bits. The architecture and compiler in question appears to use signed 8-bit `char` values.

This means that any value with the highest bit (bit 7) will be a negative value. So 0x80 as a `char` becomes -128 decimal.

The constant 0x80 is not a `char` value, it is an `int` value.

So when you compare -128 with 0x80 (128) they are not the same, and can never be, and the compiler figures this out and issues a warning.

There are a variety of ways to achieve this, here are a few possible scenarios:

First, we can cast either value to the type of the other:

```
if (((int)byte) & 0xff == 0x80)
```

or

```
if (byte == (char)0x80)
```

Alternatively, we can make the constant into a `char` value, rather than an `int` value.

```
if (byte == '\200')     // Octal 200 = 0x80.
```

or

```
if (byte == '\x80')
```

Alternatively, use an `unsigned char byte = 0x80;` - specifying that it's an unsigned char will ensure that it doesn't "flip to negative".

Comment: For completeness I'd add that you can also compile (under clang and gcc at least) with `-funsigned-char`, which will force all `char`s to be unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

The `signed char` type can contain values `0x7f` to `-0x80` for a total of 256 values.  The `unsigned char` type can contain the value `0x80` as the maximum value is `0xff`.  It appears that the implementation of the `char` type that you are using is a `signed char` type.

Assigning `0x80` to a `signed char` forces a value overflow, making the value be `-0x80`.  The `signed char` type cannot represent `0x80` to the system as it is always interpreted as `-0x80`.  This is because the most significant bit is used as the sign bit.

Your comparison could be successful if you used a bitwise and: `byte & 0x80`.  Note that the result of this operation does not imply equality in either direction, merely whether the most significant bit is set.

Comment: The `char` type can be signed or unsigned, so your first sentence is not always true.

Comment: The test with `&` is not equivalent to equality.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Correct. `byte & 0x80` can evaluate to true even if `byte` doesn't contain `0x80`. For example, `0x80 & 0x81` would evaluate to true.

Comment: It will overflow, but the value will be -128, not -1!